# What does this Cantonese sentence "冧哥覆咗你未?" mean in English?

Tags: translation, cantonese

What does this Cantonese sentence "冧哥覆咗你未" mean in English?

Answer (score 4):

冧哥 (the subject) roughly means "Mr. Sweet talk" (冧 has the meaning of "sweet talk" or "coax"; adding 哥 to the end of a noun is a common way to nickname someone. )

覆咗 = replied (覆 is short for 答覆; 咗 is a word particle that indicates the verb is completed, It functions the same as 了 in Mandarin)

你 = you (the object)

未 = has not/ not yet

"**冧哥覆咗你未?**" = "Mr. Sweet talk replied you? (or he) has not?" = "**Has Mr. Sweet talk replied you yet?**"

Comment: The policy of this forum is not to be a free translation service. However, this sentence is in Cantonese, it might be hard for Mandarin speaker to translate it. My answer is mainly for helping Mandarin speakers to understand Cantonese more.

Comment: I love answers to non-Mandarin questions, only being a Mandarin speaker myself. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Others have translated the full sentence into English. I just want to add that 冧哥 as "Mr. Sweet talk" is not a very common usage in Cantonese.